# how to create bean if another bean exists or not but don't throw exception

Tags: spring, spring-bean

i have auto-config like shown below

```java
public class ConfigClass {

    //create a builder
    @Bean
    public Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    //create a bean if SampleBean exists

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnBean(SampleBean.class, Builder.class)
    public SomeClass someClass(@Qualifier("builder") Builder builder, SampleBean sampleBean) {
        builder.set(sampleBean);
        return builder.getSomeClass();
    }

    //create a bean if above doesn't create a bean
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnBean(SomeClass.class)
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean("someClass")
    public SomeClass someClass1(@Qualifier("builder") Builder builder) {
        return builder.getSomeClass();
    }
}
```

I have auto-config for SampleBean

```java
public class SampleBeanConfig{
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty("example.property")
    public SampleBean (){
        return new SampleBean();
    }
}
```

so, what i'm testing is i want to create SomeClass bean either SampleBean exists or not.
i have commented the property "example.property". but spring is throwing bean not found exception in ConfigClass that SampleBean is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would be to add the same *@ConditionalOnProperty* annotation to *someClass* bean:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass(SampleBean.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty("example.property")
public SomeClass someClass(Builder builder, SampleBean sampleBean) {
    builder.set(sampleBean);
    return builder.getSomeClass();
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(SomeClass.class)
public SomeClass someClass1(Builder builder) {
    return builder.getSomeClass();
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty("example.property")
public SampleBean sampleBean() {
    return new SampleBean();
}
```

So someClass will be created only along with sampleBean (as they have the same annotation)

Hope it will helps you :)